# How to create a menu of taxonomies in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I'm sure this should be simple, though i'm finding it incredibly frustrating...

I am using Orchard v1.7.1. I also have the Taxonomies module installed.

I have created a Taxonomy 'Products' and the image below shows its child terms

[image]

I would like to create a page that displays the top level terms only - I.E 'Abrasives, Adhesives, Backup Pads'. Then I would like to be able to click one of these and then see the child terms. Finally, clicking a child term would show content associated to that taxonomy.

The part I am struggling with is the projection.

I have tried creating a projection, below is just one of the many types i have tried

[image]

And in the 'Prods' filter I tried setting `is one of` and choosing 'Products' from the list.

Now when i view this projection I see EVERYTHING - there is a page with a link to every single parent/child of this taxonomy and also another taxonomy i have created.

when i go back into the 'prods' filter i find that all my root taxonomies are selected - it's like its not actually storing my selection.

Ultimately, I could do with some help setting this 'seemingly' simple thing up..

I am trying to achieve this without having to code up my own module.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Filter on your taxonomy's terms type, not taxonomy.

Comment: Does't that mean every time I add terms I need to update the query?

Comment: Not at all. When you create a taxonomy, a new type gets automatically created for its terms. Adding terms means there are more items of that new type, but the query itself is filtered by the type, not by specific items of that type. So yes, changes will be picked up automatically by the query. I'm doing exactly that on my own web site, so I know it works.

Comment: yes, I've tried that and when I have a query on 'SiteWide Term' - i get everything beneath that in the results. I'm aiming to essentially list just the parents under that term, then click a parent and then show any child terms. is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you'll need an additional filter for that. Maybe on the Path property of TermPart.

Comment: Are you able to give a more specific example? Something a little more end-to-end? The more I dig into this the more frustrated I seem to be getting with something that I would have thought would be simple to do.......

Comment: The code for Orchard.Taxonomies.Projections.TermsFilter is a good example of how to build a filter.

Comment: How did you solve this?? I am trying something similar for 2 days now and am not able to apprehend this functionality